# How to show booked dates in a different color in Materialize datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker, materialize

I am using Materialize datepicker to choose a date for bookings and I want to display the already booked dates (info can be gained from the database) in 'red' color in the datepicker. How can I do this? Any help is much appreciated.

**Here is my html code for the datepicker -**

```
<div class="input-field">
     <i class="material-icons prefix">today</i>
     <input id="calender" format="yyyy-MM-dd" type="text" class="datepicker" ng-model="later.from" required>
     <label for="calender">From</label>
</div>
```

**The jquery code -**

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        formatSubmit: 'yyyy/mm/dd'
    });
```

[Here is a view of my current datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDWnj.png)

In the datepicker functionality, using objects as a range of dates as in - `$('.datepicker').pickadate({ disable: [ { from: [2016,2,14], to: [2016,2,27] } ] })` also doesn't work for me.

Comment: How you are getting already booked dates as? What backend?

Comment: I am using Jax-RS to write Java Web Services in my backend operations. Whenever somebody places a booking, it goes to the borrow_device table in my Mysql database and I can identify the booked dates from the color column in that table.

Comment: Sorry to say but I don't have any knowledge on Jax-RS or Java Web Services, but if you could help me with how you send the date to the UI, to know these dates has to be marked red or booked, I can try to help you on that..

Comment: I can get the booked dates to the front-end from the database using {{devices[whichItem].transaction_Mode == 'orange'}}. '<p id="fromDate" > {{$('.datepicker').pickadate() | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}} </p>' is how I get the date and in my controller i refer it as later.from since I send the picked date through a form

Comment: Are you using `ajax`? how will you get it to UI? do you have any `model` concept?

Comment: No i dont use ajax. This datepicker is in a form, so I send the data through a POST call to the database. I access those data in the front-end  using {{devices[whichItem].from_Date}}

Comment: In the datepicker functionality, using objects as a range of dates as in - $('.datepicker').pickadate({
  disable: [
    { from: [2016,2,14], to: [2016,2,27] }
  ]
}) also doesn't work for me.

Comment: Doesn't work? You are getting any error?

Comment: No,  $('.datepicker').set('disable', [
  { from: [14,0], to: [16,30] }
]) also doesn't work. No error given.

Comment: Doesn't work in the sense you are able to click the date?? Execute the same code again in console..

Comment: I can click the date but the 'disabled' dates (from the code) are not shown

Comment: It has been mentioned that **At this time, not all `pickadate.js` options are working with our implementation**.. So I think they have to update.. **[Source](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#date-picker)**

Comment: Yeah probably that's the issue cz Materialize Datepicker isn't updated yet for all the functionalities. I think I might have to use another calendar to display disabled dates, any suggestions of a properly working one?

Comment: Well I suggest to create an issue in **[`github`](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues)** and ask for the solution with them.. Or else you have a very long functionality to be implemented when you continue with this...